# py2exe pydrive error ssl.pyc file not found

Tags: py2exe, pydrive

With fear and trembling I post my first question here. I have a simple program which downloads and uploads to/from google drive using `pydrive` calling `authorizeGdrive` (where it's choking now) `downloadFile`, `uploadFile`. When it builds I get a long list of files that are missing. Here are the first several:

> 'Crypto.Hash', 'Crypto.PublicKey', 'Crypto.Signature',
>   'Crypto.Util.asn1', 'OpenSSL', '_scproxy', '_sysconfigdata',
>   'ca_certs_locater', 'discovery_cache.DISCOVERY_DOC_MAX_AGE'

and, of course, the build runs with the error "no such file ssl.pyc" .

My question is Where are these missing files? What do I need to include in the setup.py file?